# Using Tabs html css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this html fragment which represent a tabbed interface, I have been looking around how to enable the tab selection on click but no use, I even programmed it manually using javascript, it worked, but i believe this is not the professional way to do it, there must be some jquery solution. I am posting below the html code fragment

```
<div class="services">
    <div class="tabs">  

    <!--Top Tabs panel-->

    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav" id="services">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#ui-tabs-currency"><span>العملات</span></a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><a href="#ui-tabs-weather"><span>حالة الطفس</span></a></li>
    </ul>                                         

    <!--Bottom Tabs panel-->                        

    <div id="ui-tabs-currency" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content">
        <div class="pnl">
        sdfdsfsf
        </div>                                          
    </div>

    <div id="ui-tabs-weather" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-tabs-hide">
        <div class="pnl">
        hhhhhhhhhhhhh
        </div>              
    </div>

    <div class="more"></div>                

    </div> <!-- End of tabs -->                
</div> <!-- End of services -->
```

Comment: jQuery *is* javascript. If you've already come up with a solution that works using javascript, why do you need a jQuery solution?

Comment: I think vanilla Javascript is even better - you save 40K of bandwidth by not including jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery-ui`

**HTML**

```
<div class="services">
    <div class="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-currency">العملات</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-weather">حالة الطفس</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="tabs-currency"><p>sdfdsfsf</p></div>

        <div id="tabs-weather"><p>hhhhhhhhhhhhh</p></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".tabs" ).tabs();
});​
```

[***See the working demo here***](http://jsfiddle.net/tYz8K/) and [***reference Here***](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Comment: *"have to use"* it's an overstatement, but yes - that's definitely an option worth considering ;-)

Comment: OP mentioned `jQuery` so I think he should to use `jQuery ui` as the simplest and best IMO.

Comment: I've changed `have to` to should, hope it's okay ? :-)

Comment: "can" or "might want" would be better :))))) +1 Your solution is really the simplest

Comment: Thank you guys that was very helpful, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is JavaScript, there is no "professional" way of doing this. There is only the method that best suits the need. If your method works, it works. If you want to see how it can be made better, consider posting the code on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Take a look at [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) if you want to see a jQuery way of doing this. Although, judging from your class names, you might already be using this... which leads me to wonder what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a jQuery solution, then you should use [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you specifically want that code to work? if not this works really nicely. just drop your table in where it says (and probably you'll want to remove the

tags there now

```
<div id="selector">

</div>
<div class="tabs">
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content1 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked >
    <label for="tab1">
       <i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span>Projects</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content2 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">
        <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Flash-Mobs</span>
    </label>
    <!-- Radio button and lable for #tab-content3 -->
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
    <label for="tab3">
       <i class="fa fa-heartbeat" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Movement</span>
    </label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Positive Action Projects</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content1 -->
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
        <h3>Internatonal Positive Action Days</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
    <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
     <h3>Grow the Movement</h3>
        <p><!-- Tab content here --></p>
    </div> <!-- #tab-content2 -->
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .tabs {
    max-width: 90%;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 75px auto;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
.tabs:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.tabs input[type=radio] {
    display:none;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #ccc;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tabs label span {
    display: none;
}
.tabs label i {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    color: #3498db;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
}
.tab-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.tab-content * {
    -webkit-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
    animation: scale 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    opacity: 0;
    }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    opacity: 0.5;
    }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
    background: #FFF;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px #3498db;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #3498db;
    color: #3498db;
}
#tab1:checked ~ #tab-content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #tab-content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #tab-content3 {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .tabs i {
        padding: 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .tabs label span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tabs {
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    }
}
```